# How to use Storyboard to add Menu to NSTableView?

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa, storyboard

I try to add a context menu to a `NSTableView` using the interface builder with a storyboard. But I get a strange error message at runtime.

First I created the menu in the scene where the `NSTableView` is located:

[image]

Next I connect the `menu` outlet of the `NSTableView` to the menu:

[image]

The object structure looks like this:

[image]

If I start the application, as soon this view is displayed I get this strange error message:

```
... Missing placeholder for identifier UpstreamPlaceholder-6yv-X7-Kie
... Attempted to set object of class NSNibExternalObjectPlaceholder as the menu of a NSTableView (0x100b25260).  Ignored.
```

The view is loaded manually in the code using this method:

```
eventEditorViewController =
    self.storyboard!.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("eventEditor") as? NSViewController
```

**What could be the reason for this error message?**

Comment: Should we assume you've tried deleting the outlet connection and re-connecting it?  If you connect the menu to another object (the scroll view, for example), do you get the same error?

Comment: @PhillipMills I connected the menu to the scroll view and got the same error message. If I use the menu in the same context but with the scene "automatically" loaded, everything works fine. Seems the problem is somehow with the `instantiateControllerWithIdentifier` method.

Comment: Same thing for `NSTableView` delegate outlet. Ever solved?

Comment: @IanBytchek No, I solved it by adding the context menu in the initialisation (`viewDidLoad()`) programatically.

Comment: I've gotten similar (but different) errors in a similar context, which specifically complained about not having a strong ref to the menu.  If you manually make an IBOutlet for the menu, in your controller, and save a strong ref, does it work?